# Using `dask` to fill `boost_histograms` stored in class in parallel

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed, awkward-array, boost-histogram

I have an `dask` -`boost_histogram` question. I have a code structure as follows:

I have a class defined in some script:

```
class MyHist:
     def __init__(....):
         self.bh = None
     def make_hist(...):
           axis = bh.axis.Regular(....)
     @dask.delayed
     def fill_hist(data)
         self.bh.fill(data)
```

and in another script I want to fill multiple histograms in parallel with dask. The data are `awkward` arrays that I read from input, and for that I do something like:

```
     from dask.distributed import Client
     cl = Client()
     histos = [MyHist(..), MyHist(another...)]
     for i, file in enumerate(files):
         data = dask.delayed(open_file(file))
         for myhist in histos:
             if i ==0:  myhist.make_hist()
             fill_results.append(myhist.fill_hist(data)
      dask.compute(*fill_results)
```

If I then try to call

```
for j, h in enumerate(histos):
        print(h.bh)
```

I get empty histograms. However, if I print the boost histogram inside the `fill_hist` funciton, the histograms seem to be filled.

Does the `dask` computation create a deep copy or something of the `MyHist` object to perform the computation, and hence fill the `bh` associated with that copy? or am I doing something wrong here?

=====================================================================
Update:

I see a similar or worse wall-time when using dask to read and fill than using sequential code. This is the case whether or not I use my code or the suggested answer. For an example that doesn't use an intermediate class, I've written the following code:

```
files = get_input_file_paths('myprocess')

@dask.delayed
def make_a_var(jet_pt):
    jets_pt = copy(jet_pt)
    jets_pt = ak.mask(jets_pt, ak.count(jets_pt, axis=1)>=1)
    return jets_pt[:, 0]*1e-3

@dask.delayed
def make_and_fill(data, axes):
    h = bh.Histogram(*axes, storage=bh.storage.Weight())
    h.fill(data)
    return h 

batch_size = 4
results = []
for i in range(0, len(files), batch_size):
    batch = []
    for j, file in enumerate(files[i:i+batch_size]):
        data = dask.delayed(read_file(file))
        var = data['jet_pt']
        new_var = make_a_var(var)
        new_var = new_pt.to_numpy() # Needed bc bh breaks for masked ak arrays
        new_var= new_var.compressed()
        for k in range(10):
            axes = (bh.axis.Regular(25, 0, 250), )
            h = make_and_fill(new_var, axes)
            batch.append(h)
    results.append(batch)
dask.compute(*results)
```

It takes a similar amount of wall-time ~7s to run this code sequentially as well as with dask, for `k in range(10)`. For `k in range(100)` the parallel code takes 15s and sequential takes 21s, which is not as big of an improvement as I would have thought.

Comment: This is just a guess, but if the distributed Dask job sends a copy of the histogram to remote workers ("remote" might mean other processes on the same computer) because it has to serialize them to do so, then you might be filling the remote histogram, not your local ones. That would be why you don't see any changes in the local ones: that copy didn't change. If you're going to fill histograms remotely, you have to have the remote workers make their own (initially zero) histograms, fill them and then return them from the function so that you can add the filled histograms on your local computer.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is in-line with what I thought could be happening. If I return the histogram from the fill function, I can access it from the `fill_results` list. Then I can set the class attribute to the value computed...

Answer (score 1):

I believe Jim's comment is correct w.r.t. the source of the problem; I'll also offer a solution I think may be helpful in solving the problem:

I think the definition of your class makes it difficult to work correctly with `dask`; that is, you probably will have an easier time if your `fill_hist` method was actually a free function. And in your loop you are actually calling `dask.delayed` on an already `delayed` method (this is likely not what you want to do):

```py
fill_results.append(dask.delayed(myhist.fill_hist(data))
#                                       ^^^^^^^^^
#                                 already delayed method
```

My suggestion would be to go with a free function:

```py
@dask.delayed
def fill_hist(data, axes, storage=None):
    storage = storage or bh.storage.Double()
    h = bh.Histogram(*axes, storage=storage)
    h.fill(data)
    return h

@dask.delayed
def open_file(fname):
    data = some_function_to_get_data(fname)
    return data

axes = (bh.axis.Regular(100, -10, 10),)  # tuple with a single axis
tasks = []
for f in files:
    data = open_file(f)
    hist = fill_hist(data=data, axes=axes)
    tasks.append(hist)

results = dask.compute(tasks)
```

This pattern is very similar to how [`dask-histogram`](https://github.com/dask-contrib/dask-histogram) works on its backend, (and `dask-histogram` has support for `dask-awkward`!)

Comment: Thanks for that! Indeed calling delayed on a delayed function is a typo in the question and I'm not doing it in my code. The problem for me going to a free function like that is the fact that I am writing some framework to be able to process histograms of various sorts, and I write the framework so that the user passes the histogram settings to a `Hist` class which manages it. I feel like extracting all histogram information (e.g. binning, selection, weights) from the class then dumping them all onto a free function goes against the point of having a class. Am I wrong to say that?

Comment: and for some reason it seems to me that parallelsing the reading and filling even with your suggested method, seems to take a longer wall-time that the sequential version of the code. CPU time does improve, but it seems like there is a long time where either the workers aren't doing anything or there is a `transfer-somefunction` task going on. Any ideas why that could be the case?

Comment: On the performance topic: Dask speeding up your workflow is dependent on a wide range of things. To first order, if your dataset fits in memory on the machine you're using, it's unlikely that Dask will speed things up unless you're making 100s/1000s of histograms in parallel over the same data. If your dataset is large and doesn't fit in memory, Dask can likely help in that situation. It's hard to know exactly without a detailed look at your dataset. On code design: You can still use a class based approach that just wraps the delayed free functions. I'd suggest giving that a try.